# How to get subgroup-wise summary over a vector?

Tags: r

I know how to solve that in a c-style for-loop method, but I just want to figure out how to solve it in R-mindset---the functional programming paradigm.

Say, `data <- (10,21,4,34,53,65,24,24,65)` has 9 elements. I want to get the 1st 3 elements to be applied by function `sum` or `average`, and go on this for the 2nd 3, and 3rd 3, and finally get 3 `sum`/`average` figures together as a vector. just as something like:

```
bi = [1:3]
ei = [7:9]
seq(sum(data[bi]), sum(data[ei]), by=3)
```

But I don't know how to express in R to make the `by` apply to the index `bi`? Thus the result should be:

```
c(sum(data[1:3]), sum(data[4:6]), sum(data[7:9]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
data.frame(data=c(10,21,4,34,53,65,24,24,65)) %>%
    mutate(cuts=cut2(1:length(data), cuts=1:ceiling(length(data)/3))) %>%
    group_by(cuts) %>% summarise(mean=mean(data), sum=sum(data), n=n())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
m<-matrix(data,nr=5,byrow=T)
apply(m,1,mean)
apply(m,1,sum)
```

Comment: Better options are `rowSums`, `rowMeans`